# Понятие CSS префикс

Tags: cms

Объясните мне, что это и как можно применить при вёрстке сайта?

[Движок InstantCMS](http://www.instantcms.ru/)

Answer (score 4):

[Тынц](http://yapro.ru/web-master/css/vendornie-prefiksi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, лучше никак их не применять, т.к. для каждого браузера они свои и потом могут быть траблы с кросбраузерностью.

Comment: ну мало-ли хочется, пробывать и смотреть надо + кругом костыли ставить =) и все когда-то заработает